# In a group of 30 people, must at least 3 have been born in the same month? Why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

This is a pigeon hole principle problem and I'm not sure how I can word this to prove that at least 3 have been born in the same month out of 30 people?

Comment: I can't even guess what you mean to ask here.  Should note that if three people are born during a math class, not a lot of math will be discussed.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant "month" :((( fixed it now

Comment: I'm guessing we should prove that, "In any group of 30 people, at least three must have been born in the same month" but that's a bit past meeting the OP half way.

Comment: I thought of that, but then you went out of your way to say "math class" in the text.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I fixed that =/ I haven't gotten much sleep lately

Comment: Hint:  If two are born in January, two in February, and so on, that accounts for $24$ people.

Comment: So 6 people must repeat the months for the third time. Is that it? I'm very confused on what to put as my answer for these pigeon hole problems. Just a verbal explanation?

Comment: I'd write something like:  Let $s_k$ be the number of people born in month $k$.  Of course $\sum s_k=30$.  But if $s_k≤2\;\forall k$ then $\sum s_k≤24$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why not use the actual statement of the pigeonhole principle from your textbook?

Comment: or: how many months do you need so that at most 2 people are born each month?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose , Month is Box and person is ball. Total Box is 12 and Ball is 30. Up to 24 Ball you can distribute in the box so that no Box contain more than 2 Ball.

You can put 2 Ball in each Box.But it is Impossible to add more Ball (25 Ball) so that any Box does't have more than 2 Ball. So If it impossible for 25 Ball, it is also impossible for 30 Ball.

Answer (score 0):

If no three persons were born in the same month, then you could have at most two born in January, two born in February and so on for a total of 24. Since there are more than 24 people, it is impossible that no three persons were born in the same month.